# Use scala to generate html with available libraries

Tags: html, scalatags

I am scala newbie trying to create a simple scala program to generate a html and found salatags provides an api to generate it.
I followed the [scalatags](http://www.lihaoyi.com/scalatags/) and used an example [ScalaJSExample.scala](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags/blob/master/example/src/main/scala/example/ScalaJSExample.scala) and getting error.
Below is my build.sbt file and the error that I am getting

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.Error: stub
[error] java.lang.Error: stub
[error]     at scala.scalajs.runtime.package$.linkingInfo(package.scala:193)
[error]     at scala.scalajs.runtime.package$.environmentInfo(package.scala:187)
[error]     at scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic$.global(Dynamic.scala:78)
[error]     at org.scalajs.dom.package$.window$lzycompute(package.scala:235)
[error]     at org.scalajs.dom.package$.window(package.scala:235)
[error]     at org.scalajs.dom.package$.document$lzycompute(package.scala:236)
[error]     at org.scalajs.dom.package$.document(package.scala:236)
[error]     at ScalaJSExample$.delayedEndpoint$ScalaJSExample$1(HtmlRenderer.scala:199)
[error]     at ScalaJSExample$delayedInit$body.apply(HtmlRenderer.scala:193)
[error]     at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
[error]     at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
[error]     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
[error]     at scala.App$$anonfun$main$1.apply(App.scala:76)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
[error]     at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
[error]     at scala.App$class.main(App.scala:76)
[error]     at ScalaJSExample$.main(HtmlRenderer.scala:193)
[error]     at ScalaJSExample.main(HtmlRenderer.scala)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
[error]     at sbt.Run.invokeMain(Run.scala:89)
[error]     at sbt.Run.run0(Run.scala:83)
[error]     at sbt.Run.execute$1(Run.scala:61)
[error]     at sbt.Run.$anonfun$run$4(Run.scala:73)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at sbt.util.InterfaceUtil$$anon$1.get(InterfaceUtil.scala:10)
[error]     at sbt.TrapExit$App.run(TrapExit.scala:252)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
[error]     at sbt.Run$.executeTrapExit(Run.scala:120)
[error]     at sbt.Run.run(Run.scala:73)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5(Defaults.scala:1155)
[error]     at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$bgRunTask$5$adapted(Defaults.scala:1150)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool.$anonfun$run$1(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:331)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:209)
[error]     at sbt.internal.BackgroundThreadPool$BackgroundRunnable.run(DefaultBackgroundJobService.scala:254)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Oct 6, 2017 6:39:55 PM
sbt:src>
```

and build.sbt is

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-js" % "scalajs-dom_sjs0.6_2.11" % "0.9.3",
  "org.scala-js" % "scalajs-library_2.11" % "0.6.20",
  "com.lihaoyi" % "scalatags_2.11" % "0.6.7",
  "org.scala-lang" % "scala-library" % scalaVersion.value,
  "com.lihaoyi" % "scalatex-api_2.11" % "0.3.6"
)

//Getting error with the below plugin and commented it out
//addSbtPlugin("com.lihaoyi" % "scalatex-api_2.12" % "0.3.6")

//scalatex.SbtPlugin.projectSettings
//  scalaVersion := scalaVesrion.value
```

Could someone see what is wrong and what is the simple way to generate static html as simple as

> hello World!

in scala with some available scala libraries or apis?